# Input textfield hidden when not typing

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I type inside my input form the text only shows momentarily before vanishing, the only way I can prevent this is if I keep my finger down on a letter of my keyboard.

This problem only began to occur when I made a resizeInput attribute which makes the input box change according to the value inside of it, e.g. input box gets bigger with every letter I type.

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

*** *Something is up with the jquery in the jsfiddle, the resizeInput isn't working for some reason which doesn't give you the "text only shows momentarily before vanishing" effect. However the issue is still the same if you click outside the text box***

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bx15jdw0/

**HTML**

```
<input id="message" type="text" placeholder="It's your turn to type....!" required="required">
```

Comment: @Justinas no it does not, the text vanishes when you stop entering letters, even though the resizing works. The question is NOT about resizing not working but why the text vanishes

Comment: The text disappears once the line height is applied by the browser to the newly typed text.  You have set the line height to be 15em - 15 times the size of the font.  The text is being rendered but it is vertically aligned outside the visual range.  Reduce the line height/remove it altogether or alternatively, increase the size of the input box.

Comment: @Alexandros well, i use FireFox and there is no vanishing of text

Comment: @Justinas different rendering I suppose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `line-height` from the css and include jQuery to your fiddle and it will work.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bx15jdw0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove line-height from the css and it will work

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bx15jdw0/3/

Your new CSS:

```
input 
{
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    outline:none;
 }
```

line-height is too big for the input thats why it does this. Try making it smaller and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Remove your line-height or make it smaller

http://jsfiddle.net/bx15jdw0/7/

```
input 
{
display: block;
margin: 20px;
width: auto;
height: 60px;
font-size: 50px;
color: #000000;
outline:none;
}
```